# Why this import related code works in __init__.py but not in different .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's have this `__init__.py` in a Python3 package:

```
from .mod1 import *
from .mod2 import *
from .mod3 import *
__all__ = mod1.__all__ + mod2.__all__ + mod3.__all__
```

The code looks quite simple and does what is expected: it imports from modules mod1, mod2 and mod3 all symbols that these modules have put into their `__all__` list and then a summary of all three `__all__` lists is created.

I tried to run the very same code in a module, i.e. not in the `__init__.py`. It imported the three modules, but `mod1`, `mod2` and `mod3` were undefined variables.

(BTW, if you run pylint on the original `__init__.py`, you will get this error too.)

The same statement `from .mod1 import *` creates a `mod1` object when executed in the `__init__.py`, but does not create it elsewhere. Why?

`__init__.py` is a special file, but till now, I thought only its name was special.

Comment: Bit of a side question, but: why are you doing this at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  I have a logical circuit simulator with a library of building blocks defined in multiple files. I want to be able to simply add a new file with blocks to be added to the library. I have found several recipes and now I'm testing them and learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules), this is expected behaviour:

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. `importlib` APIs, the `import` or `import-from` statements, or built-in `__import__()`) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object. For example, if package `spam` has a submodule `foo`, after importing `spam.foo`, `spam` will have an attribute `foo` which is bound to the submodule.

In other words, when you do a `from .whatever import something` *within a module*, you will magically get a `whatever` attribute bound *to the module*. Naturally, you can access module's own attributes within `__init__.py` as if they were defined as variables there. When you are in another module you cannot do it. In this sense `__init__.py` is special indeed.

Comment: I have to read your answer several times. O hope I finally got it. If x and x.y are imported, Python "makes a link" from x to y. Only x is the parent of y, no matter who is importing what.